# XPath statement to find nearest preceding sibling

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HTMLAgilityPack in a C# WPF application to loop through some anchor tags in a local HTML page and extract the href attribute.  This works great, but I then need to find the title the anchor sits under within the HTML document (which is also an anchor tag).  This should be easy enough to do with XPath, but I just can't seem to get a statement that works for all scenarios.

Here's a sample of my HTML (which I have no control over):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="#maintitle" class="title">maintitle</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="#subtitle1" class="subtitle">subtitle1</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="link1.pdf">link1</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="link2.pdf">link2</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="link3.pdf">link3</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="#subtitle2" class="subtitle">subtitle2</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="link4.pdf">link4</a></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><a href="link5.pdf">link5</a></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

After finding link1, I then want to find subtitle1.  Likewise for link2 and link3.  But for link4 and link5, I want to find subtitle2.  I'm using this XPath statement (the first section is there just to simulate the selection of an anchor tag, which I've been using with an online XPath evaluator https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html):

```
//a[@href='link4.pdf']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr//a[@class='subtitle']
```

This works for link1 to link3, but for link4 and link5 it returns both subtitle1 and subtitle2.  Adding `[1]` to `preceding-sibling::t` fixes it for link4, but breaks it for link2, link3 and link5:

```
//a[@href='link4.pdf']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[1]//a[@class='subtitle']
```

I've also tried adding `last()` to `preceding-sibling::t`, but this results in nothing being found for any of the links:

```
//a[@href='link4.pdf']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[last()]//a[@class='subtitle']
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution, but I'm by no means competent with XPath so I'm struggling.  How do I get my original XPath statement to return the closest sibling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

locator to get subtitle by link text ('link4')

> `(//a[text()='link5']/preceding::tr[.//a[@class='subtitle']])[last()]`

logic:

> `//a[text()='link4']` - get element by linked text
>
> `//a[text()='link4']/preceding::tr` - search for all tr parents
>
> `[.//a[@class='subtitle']]` - get first parent containing tag `a` with
>   class '`subtitle`'
>
> `(someLocator)[last()]` - get last element matching locator, in our case - get last parent containing tag `a` with class '`subtitle`'

another option - initially search `tr` instead of `a` element

```
(//tr[.//a[text()='link5']]/preceding-sibling::tr//a[contains(@class,'subtitle')])[last()]
```

hopefully it will help anybody to get the logic ob building locators

Comment: This still returns two `tr`s.

Comment: please check now. whole locator is `(//a[text()='link5']/preceding::tr[.//a[@class='subtitle']])[last()]`

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I actually used the following to do what I needed, but your answer got me there: `(//a[@href='link1.pdf']/ancestor::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[@class='subtitle']])[last()]//a[@class='subtitle']`

Comment: yep, its all optional, that is why i'm not writing locators, but writing logic of how they are built

Answer (score 0):

Try using the xpath :

`//a[@href='<your_input>']/preceding-sibling::tr[.//a[@class='subtitle']][1]`

where `<your_input>` could be `link1.pdf` to `link5.pdf`

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work without a bit of tweaking.  I had to add a missing: `/ancestor::tr/`

Comment: What output you are getting when you given the input `link5.pdf` in place of `your_input` ?

Comment: Yes yes, I think I had it in my first original answer, later removed it some how. Updated the answer. Thanks.